# Page.PreviousPage.FindControl is NULL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am accessing Test.aspx through two different pages. Something like this:

**Page1.aspx -------> Test.aspx <-------- Page2.aspx**

I am testing this in IE7 where `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` is not working. In IE 8+ it works. Nothing I tried is working so far and its driving me **nuts**.

I also tried putting a hidden textbox in Page1.aspx so that I can see if the control textbox is available, if it is then I know I am coming from Page1 or else Page2. This code is not working:

```
        var hidden = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("tbhidden");
```

'tbhidden' is this:  `<asp:textbox ID="tbhidden" runat="server" visible = "false"/>`

How would you crack this problem?

Comment: When you say, "I am accessing Test.aspx", - how does this happen, exactly? What code did you write in order to "access" the page?

Comment: i am going to Test.aspx by a drop down...through JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the UrlReferrer will be blank for the first page bought up when a browser is started?

You can only use the Page.PreviousPage object if you are doing a server side redirect using the Server.Transfer command

**Breaking the problem down**

If you are using anchors to get to the test page then add a parameter to it in page1 and 2

```
<a href="test.aspx?from=page1 ...>
```

and pick it up in the test page using 
    Request.QueryString["from"]

If you are using a post then amend the form action in page1 and 2

```
<form action="test.aspx?from=page1 ...>
```

This will double check that you are coming from the correct page.

**Another** good tip is to download the tool called "Fiddler", it intercepts the website posts and gives a nicely formatted breakdown of all the referral values and page requests that occur.

Comment: Oh! So Page.PreviousPage is not going to help because I am not doing that. So what should I do?

Comment: Gave a double check process to help break it down

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following style to the textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbhidden" runat="server" 
     style="display:none; position:absolute; left:-500px" Width="0px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

remove the `Visible="false"`  from Textbox Property

Comment: How do I test on the Test.aspx that whether this control was present in Page1.aspx page?

Comment: Okay! Let me give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I tried, it is throwing me this err: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}